# Gnome-shell and gnome desktop installation failed on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome

So I did a fresh installation of 14.04 lts today and i wanted to install gnome shell or ubuntu-gnome-desktop on my linux but it is a problem there :

```
Aspire-E5-571G:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Aspire-E5-571G:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-gnome-desktop : Depends: gdm but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: gnome-session but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: gnome-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: gnome-shell-extensions but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So.. my question is what is going on here. Btw i used to get gnome-shell not even once and it was working. Anyway i tried everything from another topics and from here : [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) as well. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OK here is what i did and what solve this problem somehow..**

---

Install `synaptics` then open it up. When u are in there search for this `gnome-settings-daemon-schemas`. Right click on it and Install/Update/Upgrade (whatever it shows and is similar to it). I also upgraded another files with *gnome* in name for any case. `Apply` and reboot.

---

**Sadly**.. it was not the end for me. I was not able to login and all i had to do was

> CTRL + ALT + F1

..login and

> $ Sudo apt-get install gnome

..Reboot and everything was working just fine. If u want ubuntu unix desktop just install it manually.